# Bounding rectangle of a geography

Tags: postgis, postgresql, extents, geography-data-type

How to get a bounding box (in the form of a Polygon, or anything else where it's easy to extract the corner coordinates from) of a given `Geography` item? Something that would look like:

```
SELECT Boundary(geog) AS boundingBox FROM segments;
```

Where `geog` is a `MULTILINE` geography.

Seems like a trivial question, but my experience so far is limited and I did not have any luck with the docs (http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-1.5/reference.html ) Tried `ST_Boundary` and `Box2D` but they do not work on geographies.

Comment: Does [`ST_Envelope`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_Envelope.html) work with `geography`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast the geography to a geometry type and then call [ST_Envelope](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Envelope.html) on the geometry.

```
SELECT ST_Envelope(geog::geometry) as boundingBox FROM segments;
```